# Find maximum value between specified date range

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, max, excel-indirect

I have a range of daily dates in column G and a range of stock prices in column H. I would like to find a rolling 52 week high, i.e. the highest stock price in column H between the current date and the same date 1 year prior.

I am using the following formula:

`MAX(IF($G$5:$G$10757>=EDATE(G5,-12),IF($G$5:$G$10757<=G5,$H$5:$H$10757)))`

So, the IF conditions specify the date range as being in between G5 and G5 less 12 months, and is looking for the corresponding value in column H.

After I type the formula, I press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. It seems to work for the first calculation, but I cannot fill the formula down for the entire range of dates. I just get the same value repeating over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is possible without an array formula. maybe:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("H"&MATCH(G5-365,G:G,0)&":"&"H"&ROW()),0)
```

would suit (if you are flexible about leap years!). (Will return #N/A until there are more than 365 days of data).

Edit Same result but without errors showing:

```
=IFERROR(MAX(INDIRECT("H"&ROW()-369&":H"&ROW())),"")
```